# Is there a way to filter a dataframe in pandas that will bring me only the fisrt x apperences of all the values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a column with only 5 values reapeted multiple times. I was wondering if there is a way to filter this dataframe in a way that will return the fisrt x times that all the 5 values appear in the dataframe. It would be something similar to drop_duplicates(keep='first') but instead of only keeping the first value that appears, it would keep the value the first x times it appears.

I think I can do that using iterrows(), but that is not a very efficient way to solve this. I was looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to what I was looking for is:

```
(df.sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False)
 .groupby('short_name').head(2)
 .reset_index())
```